# How to interpolate environmental variable as number in json body of request in Postman?

Tags: postman

My API consumes data in JSON where some fields need to be numbers. I have some shared data in my environmental variables, where one entry is `user_id`, which in my case is an integer, so I need to provide it to my API as a number.

I've tried to inline value `"userId": {{user_id}}`, but it highlights coma after last `}` and API can't see what is coming to it. In Postman console I can see that actual value sent is this:

```
"user": {{user_id}},
```

So it doesn't seem to work. And using `"userId": "{{user_id}}"` doesn't work in my case as user id will be sent as a string.

**How to interpolate environmental variable as number in json body of request?**

Comment: Can you provide more details? The complete JSON body (after removing sensitive data) would help. I tried with a simple one-line JSON body using the `"user": {{user_id}}` notation and it worked.

Comment: @Arlemi hm... now it works for some reason with single property. will try with whole body. I had mistyped the name of environmental variable.

Answer (score 0):

I've mistyped the name of an environmental variable. I was using `{{user_id}}`, instead of `{{userID}}` that is in my environment, thus interpolation resulted in the different wrong thing.